# How to provide a condition within Chef recipe to see if it running under test kitchen?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I am using encrypted data bags within Chef and I want to add a condition within my Chef recipe as follows:

```
If (test kitchen) then
  encryptkey = data_bag_item("tokens", "encryptkey")

If ( not test kitchen ) then
  secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret")
  encryptkey = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("tokens", "encryptkey", secret)
```

I have added `data_bags_path` and `encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path` within `kitchen.yml` as follows:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  chef_omnibus_url: omni-url/chef/install.sh
  roles_path: 'test/integration/default/roles'
  data_bags_path: "test/integration/default/data_bags"
  encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path: "test/integration/default/encrypted_data_bag_secret"
```

Comment: See https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/issues/458 for chef's official non-answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the attributes in your kitchen.yaml.

```
  suites:
  - name: default
    data_bags_path: 'databags'
    run_list:
      - recipe[x::y]
    attributes: {'kitchen' : 'true' }
```

Inside your recipe put if condition using the value of node['chef-mode'].

```
if node['kitchen'] == 'true'
    #something
else
   #else 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `data_bag_item("tokens", "encryptkey")` for both. It will take care of decryption for you automatically.

Comment: But, if it is not kitchen test and the recipe is running directly on the server node, then how the node will know about the secret encryption key. Remember, in case of kitchen test I specifying the encryption key as `encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path: "test/integration/default/encrypted_data_bag_secret"` within `kitchen.yml `

Comment: The path to the secret is configured in your `client.rb` but what you have there is the default I'm pretty sure. Chef handles loading the secret for you internally.

Comment: I am getting this error `ERROR: No secret specified and no secret found at /etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret` when I use  `data_bag_item("tokens", "encryptkey")`

Comment: do you think i should do `data_bag_item("tokens", "encryptkey", "secret")` instead?

Comment: Is your secret in that file? If not, put it there.