# how to get information about chef provisioner (chef-zero or not) inside a chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, chef-zero

In my recipe I want to find out the the mode in which chef is running and load from data bag based on that. If it is running chef-zero then I will load the data bag in a specific way and if not in a different way .

```
if Chef::Config[:zero] == 'true'
  //Load unencryted databag from local
else
 //Load encrypted databag
end
```

But currently it always enters the else block. I am running kitchen with

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - The solution i was looking for is using kitchen attributes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429417/888070

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `data_bag_item()` helper it will handle this for you internally. It is better to avoid explicit branching whenever possible.

Comment: Well. This will not work for us . Do you know of a way to check the chef mode ?

Comment: There is nothing specific, you'll have to add an attribute yourself in your kitchen config or check for `/tmp/kitchen` (or the equiv on other platforms).

Comment: But seriously you will regret this :)